# Set history tracking on contact object details page

Tags: page-layout, history-tracking

I have clicked on set history tracking button and set few field in this and then save and now I want to show history tracking in related list but the thing is when I am edit the layout there is no any history tracking list there only 
Approval History and other history there but history tracking list not there how I can add/show so track the details who changed.

Comment: is this classic or lightning?

Comment: in classic org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to `Enable History Tracking` option on Contact.
2. Set the fields whom you need to track histories.
3. Go to the Page Layout in `Edit` mode, select the `Related lists`and from there select `Contact History`.

[image: Contact History Related List]